# Slice after `unstack` and `set_index`

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a simple question about slicing after using `unstack`.

My longitudinal/panel dataset takes the `longfile` form below (code for data entry is below the question).

```
    time x  y
USA 1    5  10
USA 2    5  12
USA 3    6  13
CAN 1    2  2
CAN 2    2  3
CAN 3    4  5
```

I then `unstack` the data into a `widefile`, indexed by time, as below:

```
df1 = df.reset_index().set_index(['time','index']).unstack(-1)
print(df1)
```

which gives

```
        x       y    
index CAN USA CAN USA
time                 
1       2   5   2  10
2       2   5   3  12
3       4   6   5  13
```

I'd like to now slice the widefile, `df1`, based on the time so that:

- `train` contains `t==1` and `t==2`
- `test` contains `t==3` .

I've tried this:

```
train = df1[(df.time=='1')|(df.time=='2')]
```

and this:

```
train = df1[(df.time==1)|(df.time==2)]
```

but both give errors.

My desired output is:

`train`

```
        x       y    
index CAN USA CAN USA
time                 
1       2   5   2  10
2       2   5   3  12
```

and
`test`

```
        x       y    
index CAN USA CAN USA
time                 
3       4   6   5  13
```

## Code for Data Entry

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

data = np.array([['country','time','x','y'],
                ['USA',1, 5, 10],
                ['USA',2, 5, 12],
                ['USA',3,6, 13],
                ['CAN',1,2, 2],
                ['CAN',2,2, 3],
                ['CAN',3,4, 5]],                
               )
                
df = pd.DataFrame(data=data[1:,1:],
                  index=data[1:,0],
                  columns=data[0,1:])

df
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First the `time` is `index` name , so it is `index` not column anymore , we need use `.index` , 2nd you need use the `df1` not `df`

```
train = df1[df1.index.isin([1,2])]
train
Out[219]: 
        x       y    
index CAN USA CAN USA
time                 
1       2   5   2  10
2       2   5   3  12
```